# Is there any way to see full content of Facebook posts without clicking "See more"

Tags: facebook, google-chrome

On Chrome for desktop, when browsing Facebook, long posts are not shown in full.

I need to always click "See more" to view each of them.

Is it possible to make Chrome to always show those posts in full without me click "See more" links.